# Convert local file (shp/CSV) into Earth Engine (EE) object

Tags: google-earth-engine, geopandas, jupyter-notebook

I work on Jupyter lab notebook on my local PC.
I want to download images from Google Earth Engine based on a shape I have, which is a GeoPandas.

The GeoPandas dataframe I have is coming from a shapefile that I have on my local computer, that was manipulated on Jupyter lab (I have applied the envelope function on polygons I have).
When I try to convert it to EE object, it never works:

```
#plots is the dataframe that I have uploaded from a shapefile that is local on my computer
fc = geemap.geopandas_to_ee(plots)
```

It works only if I save the data on the GEE platform as asset.
**Is there any way I can convert local files on my PC to EE object without manually upload them as assets to EE platform?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert your dataframe to GeoJSON (https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_json.html). The GeoJSON can then be used to generate an `ee.FeatureCollection`, which you finally use to filter your `ee.ImageCollection`.

```
from geopandas import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point
import json
import ee

ee.Initialize()

d = {'col1': ['name1', 'name2'], 'geometry': [Point(10.0, 10.1), Point(10.1, 10.0)]}
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(d, crs="EPSG:4326")
geo_json = gdf.to_json()

featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(json.loads(geo_json))

imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2') \
    .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-01-05') \
    .filterBounds(featureCollection.geometry())

imageCollection.size().getInfo()
```